# Calling data from one class to another class - framework for JUnit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4

Please forgive me as I am still very new to the world of test automation. I have started out by using Selenium WebDriver with JUnit4, predominately on windows OS, although I have modified my scripts and ran them on Mac.

I want to be able to create a set of classes containing set data such as usernames, passwords, default url . Perhaps even calling them from an excel file, but for now Im happy to store the data in classes and then pass that data into other test classes. Im guessing this would be a framework of some sort.

Currently I am writing classes that all begin with something like:

```
public class ExampleSQATest{

    public static Chromedriver chrome;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void launchBrowser(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

    chrome = new ChromeDrievr();
    }
    @Test
    public void aLogin(){

    chrome.manage().window().maximize();

    chrome.navigate().to("http://mydummywebsite.com");

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector
                    ("input#UserName")));

    WebElement username = chrome.findElementByCssSelector("input#UserName");

    username.sendKeys("username");

    WebElement password = chrome.findElementByCssSelector("input#Password");
    password.sendKeys("password");
    WebElement submit = chrome.findElementByCssSelector("input[type='submit']");
    submit.click();
    }
}
```

I will then proceed to write further test methods which requires entering data, but I'd like to be able to call this data from somewhere else that is already predefined.

Can anyone provide any suitable suggestions to investigate so I can learn. Something that is a guide or tutorial. Nothing too advanced, just something that helps me get started by advising me how to set a class of methods to be called by other classes and how it all links together as a framework.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this

```
public abstract class TestBase
{

    private readonly INavigationManager navMgr;
    private readonly IWindowNavigator windowNav;
    private readonly ILoginManager loginMgr;
    // All your stuff that is common for all the tests
    protected TestBase()
    {
        this.navMgr = WebDriverManager.Get<INavigationManager>();
        this.windowNav = WebDriverManager.Get<IWindowNavigator>();
        this.loginMgr = WebDriverManager.Get<ILoginManager>();
    }}

 [TestFixture]
internal class QueriesTest : TestBase
{
    private QueryTests queryTests;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.queryTests = WebDriverManager.Get<QueryTests>();
      // all the stuff you run specific before tests in this test class.
    }

}
```

Comment: Is code applicable for the language C# and not Java?

Comment: @Django_Tester treat it as pseudo code, it's only to give you idea on how this sort of problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created test classes in webdriver-junit4, Use following two classes to call your test classes (Note-Import junit annotations)

1)Create test suite class as -

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
YourTestClass1.class,
YourTestClass2.class,[you can add more tests you have created...]
})
public class TestSuiteJU {   
}
```

2)Create class to call suite created above as-

```
public class TestExecution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuiteJU .class);
}
}
```